# PHP error: 'Class "App\Models\Admin\Job" not found' in admin panel while attempting to see job applicants - How to fix?

Tags: php, admin, panel

Error
PHP 8.2.5
10.7.1
Class "App\Models\Admin\Job" not found

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class JobApplication extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'job_id',
        'applicant_first_name',
        'applicant_last_name',
        'applicant_email',
        'applicant_phone',
        'applicant_country',
        'applicant_state',
        'applicant_street',
        'applicant_city',
        'applicant_zip_code',
        'applicant_expected_salary',
        'applicant_cover_letter',
        'applicant_cv'
    ];

    public function job()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Admin\Job');
    }
}
```

Admin panel get error when trying to see applicants for the posted jobs on the website.